# jQuery Searching an Array of Arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following and I am trying to figure out how to search the array of objects - the `call()` function is called multiple times ?

```
var arr = [];
var newData;

function call() {
    newData = $('a').attr('href');

    if($.inArray(newData, arr) == -1) {
      $.post('/blah', function(data) {
          arr.push(data);
      });
    }
}
```

`data` is like `[object{ }]` so `arr` becomes `[[object{id='1', myUrl=''}], [object{id='2', myUrl='' }]]`.

What I am trying to figure is out whether `newData` is contained within the `arr` ?

Comment: mm if `arr = []` and without populating it, you are trying to search `$.inArray(newData, arr)` which I think will always return you -1

Comment: yeah I want to check if `newData` exists in the `arr` - that is, whether it's one of the `myUrl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array contains objects, `$.inArray` will not work.  This is because objects are only equal if they are the same object, not just contain the same values.

`$.inArray` won't work here also because `newData` is a string.  It's not gonna search inside each object for you, you need to that yourself, with your own loop.

Something like this:

```
newData = $('a').attr('href');
$.each(arr, function(){
    if(this.myUrl === newData){
        $.post('/blah', function(data) {
            arr.push(data);
        });
        return false; // break once a match is found
    }
});
```

Comment: one quick question - the data returns like `[object{id='1', myUrl=''}]` so using `this.MyUrl` doesn't seem to work ? Think it needs `this[0].myUrl` ?

Answer (score 0):

The Array `arr` will contain a list of objects.  Why would `newData` be "contained" within the `arr`?  They are two separate variables.

Update - Upon further inspection this line is no good:

```
if($.inArray(newData, arr) == -1) {
```

You are essentially saying look for newData in the arr (which is empty).

Update - Here is some sample code that should work.  Here I am treating data as a plain old object (not an array of objects) with a property named "url".

http://jsfiddle.net/nWh6N/

Comment: sure so I am trying to see whether `newData` is within the array - as `myUrl` contains urls and I want to try to see if `newData` is one of these ?

Comment: well -1 just says it's not in the array - therefore it will push data to the array and then when it's called again it can search ? however, I'm unsure how to search the updated array of objects like `[[object{id='1', myUrl=''}], [object{id='2', myUrl='' }]]`